# How to dynamically change the start time in the query body of REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, date, ssjs, dynamic

I am doing a REST API call using POST method with [SSJS]. In the body of the API i am sending the following parameters.

```javascript
var start= 
     {
    "activityTypes": [
        "Wait"
    ],
 "start": "2020-06-04"
};
```

I want date to be dynamic. I have the getDate() value in a variable "date". But it is not taking the variable value. 
Tried the following ways:

```javascript
var start= 
     {
    "activityTypes": [
        "Wait"
    ],
 "start": "+date+" / +date / date 
};
```

Is there any way to have the start time dynamically without adding the value manually?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using something like the journeyHistory API, just pass in a [javascript Date object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp):

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1");

    // Get events in the last 24 hours
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var start = currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours()-24); 

    var query = {
      "definitionIds": ["a9630b5d-f34f-4b0a-ac62-dedd941f1a32"],
      "contactKeys": ["123456"],
      "start": start,
      "end": null,
      "extras": "all",
      "statuses": ["Wait"]
    }
    Write(Stringify(query));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Macca. It's working.